# Как реализовать мультимодульное приложение на laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, модули

Как реализовать мультимодульное приложение в `Laravel 5`?

У меня имеется фронт и бекэнд части.
Нужно чтобы было разделение на главный сайт и админ панель, все модели, контроллеры и виды админ панели были в одной директории скажем Backend а главный сайт в другой директории Frontend

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, что вы понимаете под мультимодульностью?

Comment: @VenZell чтобы было разделение на главный сайт и админ панель

Comment: Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос. Кроме того, уточните, что именно у вас вызывает затруднение. Пока вопрос слишком общий

Comment: Кто нибудь поможет?

Comment: в свое время делал такой вариант http://ziyahanalbeniz.blogspot.cz/2015/03/modular-structure-in-laravel-5.html